# Excel Count Current Date

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a function in excel called =today() which give you the current date.  I want to know what is the count of work days as of that date and the count of day. What formula tells you that?
For example today date is 2/15/2015
I want it to return
1. 47 = because its 47/365
2. 32 = because 32/251 work days
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```html
=NETWORKDAYS(start date,end date)
```

to calculate the number of workdays between 2 dates. Set the 1st number as 01/01/2015.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `=TODAY()` in cell A1.

You'll need the following formula to return the first day of the year (in A2)

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1)
```

This will give you the number of work days

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A2,A1)
```

This will give you the total number of days

```
=A1-A2+1
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first requirement:

```
  =DATE(2015,2,15)-DATE(2014,12,31)
```

returns `46` - 31 days in January 2015 and 15 in February. I don't know why you mention `47`.

For your second requirement:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(DATE(2014,12,31),DATE(2015,2,15))
```

returns `32` - seven 2-day weekends less than above.

Other non-working days may be incorporated as a third (optional) parameter into [NETWORKDAYS](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/NETWORKDAYS-function-5fb5a1fa-c42d-4162-a762-7b1fc97215c5).

The `DATE` functions above may be replaced with cell references or a function such as `TODAY()`.